# adding characters on mouseover using Svelte

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, svelte

This is my first time using svelte. I am also using tailwind and astro but that is irrelevant. The following component prepends `>>`  to my text when it is being hovered upon and takes the `>>`  out when it is not.

Is this the typical way to use svelte? Am I doing something wrong? I feel I am.

```html
<script>
    let spanId = "selected";
    let isMouseOver = false;

    function handleMouseOver() {
        if(!isMouseOver) {
            this.innerHTML = `<span id="${spanId}">&gt;&gt; </span>` + this.innerHTML;
            isMouseOver = true;
        }
    }

    function handleMouseOut() {
        let selectedSpan = document.getElementById(spanId);
        selectedSpan.parentNode.removeChild(selectedSpan);
        isMouseOver = false;
    }
</script>

<p
    class="hover:text-green-600 cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap"
    on:mouseover={handleMouseOver}
    on:mouseout={handleMouseOut}
>
    <slot />
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/282877/revisions#rev-body-eba3dbd2-1603-490c-9a60-5ebb5faedc32) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Thank you. I think I discovered some way to make this code follow the declarative approach of svelte. Should I answer my own question?

Comment: You can, and I have done so on some of mine like [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/263565/120114). OPs are [encouraged to answer their own questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). See also meta posts like [_Answering your own review_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/187/120114) as well as [_Self-answering questions without other answers_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/120114)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per some others in a community where I have asked:

A more idiomatic way of doing it in svelte would be to remove innerHTML completely. Svelte's declarative approach makes modifying the `innerHTML` property unnecessary.

```html
function handleMouseOver() {
  isMouseOver = true;
}
```

And later in the markup just set the markup declaratively

```html
<p
    class="hover:text-green-600 cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap"
    on:mouseover={handleMouseOver}
    on:mouseout={handleMouseOut}
>
  {#if isMouseOver}
    <span id={spanId}>&gt;&gt;</span>
  {/if}  

   <slot />
</p>
```

Essentially the code turns to:

```html
<script>
  let isMouseOver = false;
</script>

<p
    class="hover:text-green-600 cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap"
    on:mouseover={() => (isMouseOver = true)}
    on:mouseout={() => (isMouseOver = false)}
>
  {#if isMouseOver}
    <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
  {/if}  

   <slot />
</p>
```

And also only CSS (tailwind in this case) could be used as so:

```html
<p class="group hover:text-green-600 cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap">
  <span class="group-hover:inline hidden">&gt;&gt;</span> <slot />
</p>
```

Comment: Make sure to use `group-hover:inline-block` when going with the css approach if you want to add css animations